# How to execute more than one shell command using python subprocess module?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have more than one command that has to be executed on the shell and I want to the run all the commands on the same shell . I have the commands stored in a file(`command.txt`) and I want all of them to be executed in a single go using the `subprocess.run()` function in python

I tried something like this but this doesn't work.

```
subprocess.run(str(open("command.txt")),shell = True)
```

Comment: Do you know how to read a file you opened? How to extract its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subprocess.run(['sh', 'command.txt'])
```

Note that we *are not* using `shell=True` here, as we already start `sh` ourselves.